# Wordpress woocommerce weird problems

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

First of all, thank you for bothering to read this topic, I feel like this is going to be a long and painful one, as I'm trying for about 7-8 hours now to get what the hell is happening with this plugin.

I am a developer, so I know what I'm doing, and this isn't my first page I did using WordPress.

The problem started when I started reading up on woocommerce's documentations which are widely known as quite poorly documented.

Since I made a custom theme, which I have had before already, I've decided to use the overwrite method as well as the woocommerce.php method for customizing the plugin to fit the site as I'd like it to.

The woocommerce_content(); is customized now, and nicely working as well as the product pages (single product page) which are customized as well, and working.

As soon as I try to access the account features, nothing happens. I've tried adding echoes for debugging purposes to the my-account.php, but it does not echo what I write, so I assume the shortcode cannot load for some reason, because it does not reach the my-account.php page as it should, and it points somewhere else perhaps?

Then I've noticed that when I click the "Add to cart" button, it appends the element with a "View cart" button as well, so me thinking this is working, I left it as it is. For like 5 seconds, because right after a page refresh, or navigating to another page, the content of the cart gets empties, I cannot even see the cart page, nor the login page, nor the create account page, or anything in fact.

Everything is working that is inside my "wp-content\themes\mytheme\woocommerce" folder, but nothing else that is inside my 
"wp-content\themes\mytheme\woocommerce\any-subfolder"

The woocommerce system status does not show any error, nor the PHP error log, nor anything else.

I have a VERY long list of "Overrides (WooCommerce):" which I don't want to paste here because of reasons.

The only success when I was able to at least get something out from the plugin, is when I used the wordpress function "do_shortcode();" and added the myaccount or cart shortcode myself to a page, THAT worked, and printed it out, however I'd like to use the original method, so the code won't get too complex for later on.

Every other site is working fine, I'm currently running this on localhost, cookies working, sessions working, I log everything yet there is no error, mod_rewrite working correctly, yet I am stuck.

Looking for a patient gentleman to help me on this painful day...

**EDIT:**
Added "[woocommerce_my_account]" to the "shop" page which page's file is the "woocommerce.php" has actually loaded up the correct my-account.php from "themeroot/woocommerce/myaccount/my-account.php" It echoes out my debug messages as well, so the shortcodes should be working, perhaps this isn't just a woocommerce related issue?

**EDIT2:**

After fiddling around a LOT, I've come to understand that the wrapper hook it is supposed to do (div id=content and div id=main) does NOT get hooked in it, perhaps it is just a small problem, since I've removed them with remove_action, and the "Shop" page still displayed properly... I have NO idea what is going on with this plugin, but I don't have the luxury of time to fiddle around with it... This is such a pain...

**EDIT3:**

The plugin works perfectly on any other basic theme, so there is something up with my custom theme. Even after hours of searching the differences between the default theme (twenty-fifteen) and mine, I have not found the solution.

Comment: I've never had any issues with subfolders within the woocommerce folder in my theme.

Comment: @Aibrean I didn't exactly mean that is what's happening, or that is causing the problem, I just said that when accessing the page, the page itself loads up, but the file that should load up WITH the page does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem... It is of course entirely my fault, the problem is just that woocommerce has so poor documentation, I did not really thought about this.

For anyone out there creating custom themes for WordPress, please note that in order for your page.php to actually use the shortcode of the page you have navigated on, you must print out the content of the page (the_content();).

This was my solution for my mistake that took many many hours...